# integer represents the format of date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My task is to create a function that takes integer which represents the format of the Manager hiring date and displays department name, Manager Name and hiring date with this format.

i have tried this but it also fails

```
alter function FormatOfManagerHireDate(@hireDate int)
returns @t table(DeptName nvarchar(50),ManagerName nvarchar(50),HiringDate nvarchar(50) )
as 
begin 
  set @hireDate=FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'MM/dd/yy'); 
  insert into @t
  select Department.Dept_Name,Instructor.Ins_Name,Department.Manager_hiredate
  from Department inner join Instructor on Instructor.Ins_Id=Department.Dept_Manager
  where Department.Manager_hiredate =@hireDate  
return
end
```

The error is:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure FormatOfManagerHireDate, Line 7 Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: How does it fail?  If there is an error, please post it.  Also post example data and expected results.

Comment: Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure FormatOfManagerHireDate, Line 7
Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Comment: How do you anticipate going from an integer to a specific date format? Is the integer/dateformat stored in a table on your database?

Comment: If you are, as it seems, currently storing Manager_hiredate in your table as an int, then simply reproduce the logic you used to store it in the first place.

Comment: Why pass the @hiredate parameter to the function if the first thing you do is set it to another value?  What's the point of passing a parameter at all?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your problem, but at least my answer helped you find your answer. So, this is the actual solution for your task (taken from comment below):

```
alter function FormatOfManagerHireDate(@hireDateFormat int)
returns @t table(DeptName nvarchar(50), ManagerName nvarchar(50), HiringDate nvarchar(50)) as
begin
    insert into @t
    select Department.Dept_Name, Instructor.Ins_Name, convert(nvarchar(50), Department.Manager_hiredate, @hireDateFormat)
    from Department
    inner join Instructor on Instructor.Ins_Id = Department.Dept_Manager
return
end
```

Comment: alter function FormatOfManagerHireDate(@hireDateFormat int)
returns @t table(DeptName nvarchar(50),ManagerName nvarchar(50),HiringDate nvarchar(50) )
as 
begin 
insert into @t
select Department.Dept_Name,Instructor.Ins_Name,convert(nvarchar(50), Department.Manager_hiredate, @hireDateFormat)
from Department inner join Instructor on Instructor.Ins_Id=Department.Dept_Manager
return
end

Comment: Oh, you only wanted a function that returned all managers with a parameter that would just change the displayed date format! It was quite an easier task then. :)

Comment: I changed my answer to it can be the real solution. Or if you prefer you can add your own answer.